# Toggle checkbox on Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap

I made a group of checkboxes with Twitter Bootstrap. Now I would like to do a "select all" or "deselect all" button. How could I do this using a JS function?

The Twitter Bootstrap documentation says to use $().button('toggle') but it doesn't work.

Here is my code snippet:

```html
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
    <div class="input">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="btn  btn-toggle" for="colors-1-toggle-0">
                <input type="checkbox" id="colors-1-toggle-0" name="colors-1[]" value="color_c" />C
            </label>
            <label class="btn  btn-toggle" for="colors-1-toggle-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="colors-1-toggle-1" name="colors-1[]" value="color_m" />M
            </label>
            <label class="btn  btn-toggle" for="colors-1-toggle-2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="colors-1-toggle-2" name="colors-1[]" value="color_y" />Y
            </label>
            <label class="btn  btn-toggle" for="colors-1-toggle-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="colors-1-toggle-3" name="colors-1[]" value="color_k" />K
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you merv! Thanks to you I came to this solution:

```
<button id="toggle-colors" class="btn btn-info">Toggle</button>
<script>
    $('#toggle-colors').click(function() {
        $('.btn-group input[name^="colors"]').each(function(){
            // toggle checkbox
            $(this).prop('checked',!$(this).prop('checked'));
            // toggle class
            $(this).parents('label').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't use the button tag as Twitter Bootstrap recommends because it doesn't send the value per POST.

Answer (score 14):

Technically, the Twitter Bootstrap Buttons plugin is meant to work with `<button>` elements and have them behave *as though they were* radio or checkbox inputs.

Also, `$().button('toggle')` is just psuedo code, and in practice is meant to be used with a selector, e.g., `$('.btn-toggle').button('toggle')`.  However, your example is a bit substandard, since you have assigned classes intended for buttons to `<label>` elements.

Anyway, despite all that, if all you want to do is set all your input boxes to true, you could use something like:

```
$('.btn-group input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/g3mu8/)

If you wanted to do it with `<button>` elements, it would be something like this:

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/g3mu8/3/)

However, that drops a bunch of the input data which you're working with.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do this without JS

http://codepen.io/ibanez182/pen/WxKABq/

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <input type="checkbox"/> A checkbox
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
    <div class="well">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe ut molestias eius, nam neque esse eos modi corrupti harum fugit, hic recusandae praesentium, minima ipsa eligendi architecto at! Culpa, explicabo.</div>
</div>
```